# Eigen 3.3.4: What is the way to create Map<VectorXd> to 2d Block?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Say I have the following code:

```
MatrixXd v(10, 10);
auto block = v.block(5, 0, 5, 2);  // a block xpr to v
// view the block as vector
// in Eigen 3.4 it would be block.reshaped()
// but for Eigen 3.3, the following does not work:
Map<VectorXd>(block.data(), 10) = VectorXd::LinSpaced(10, 0, 1.);
// or the other way around, which errors on the constness
block = Map<MatrixXd>(VectorXd::LinSpaced(10, 0., 1.).eval().data(), 5, 2);
```

My question is, is there a good way to achieve this with Eigen 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "other way around" with a temporary will do, all you have to do is respect constness using either `Map<const MatrixXd>` or the static method `MatrixXd::Map`:

```
block = Map<const MatrixXd>(VectorXd::LinSpaced(10, 0., 1.).eval().data(), 5, 2);
block = MatrixXd::Map(VectorXd::LinSpaced(10, 0., 1.).eval().data(), 5, 2);
```